# Get child categories instead of top in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation, catalogsearch

I have issue on my site regarding layered navigation.i put all my categories under other like `default->inventory->all categories`.Now on filter or search it show inventory where i want to show sub categories.See image for results.I want to show sub categories instead of top but don't know from where i can set.[image]

Comment: You should think about reorganizing your categories, before thinking about hacking the layered navigation.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt i need such top level category.that's why i create it.

Comment: You may change this. I only recommend do change _ANYTHING_ in your structure before altering the layered navigation.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt i want to show products on home page with layered navigation.Any alternate way ?

Comment: set the home page to any category.

Comment: Means no other way ?

Comment: No, why not setting the `System > Config > Web > Default Pages > Default Web URL` to `catalog/category/view/id/7` or something alike

Comment: i have already set category page using above method.that's why my home page show layerd navigation but i put all other categories under that one.now when i search for something it show that top level. i want to show child one not top one

Comment: My question is why do you have this extra layer of category if all the other categories are under simply rename the Root Category to match what you need. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @DavidManners I think you miss something.All i want is to show listing as a home page and i set one category for that.I put all categories under that.so i can now view all categories under my setted one.But problem is that i face above issue.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman by all categories do you literally mean all the categories you have in your store?

Comment: @DavidManners yes all categories i put under that one i set for home page.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: create a "homepage" category which is not part of your category navigation. Assign all products to this category and make it the homepage. You can create an observer which always associates products to this category.